# How to replace one foldername with another in all folders and subfolders of the current directory?

Tags: ssh, rename

I have LOADS of folders (literally over 500) within a folder called 'gallery'. Each folder has a number and in each numbered galler folder there are folders for the thumbs and the images. However, earlier galleries are called 'content/large' and 'content/thumbs', whereas newer ones have 'images' and 'thumbnails'. I am writing a php gallery script, so I need all the folders with the same name.

For example, at the moment I have got:

```
gallery/028/content/large
gallery/028/content/thumbs
```

in some folders, then in others I have:

```
gallery/029/images
gallery/029/thumbnails
```

So, I firstly need to change, for example, all the folders named 'large' to 'images' and all the folders named 'thumbs' to 'thumbnails'.

Secondly, I want to move any folders that are in a subfolder 'content' up a level

```
028/content/images
```

to

```
028/images
```

So that in the end all the numbered folders have an images and thumbnails subfolder only, containing the thumbs and images for each gallery respectively.

I am trying to do all this in ssh because it saves me having to download over 700 gb of data from the server!

I'd appreciate any help!

Kirsty